# Prove that the inclusion map is continuous

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. Endow $X \times Y$ with the product space topology and $X \times \{y\}$ with the subspace topology.

Prove that $g : X \times \{y\} \rightarrow X \times Y $ is continuous.

My try:

Define $g(x,y)=(x,y)$, then note that $g$ is $I|_{X \times \{y\}}$. Hence $g$ is continuous.

To me, this proof sounds a tad too simple. Are there any comments or ways I can make this proof more rigorous/better? Or is the proof wrong from the start? I would really love to hear some constructive comments.

Comment: If you've proven that the restriction of a continuous function is continuous, then yes, that works.

Comment: you need to take $U$ an open set in $X\times Y$ and prove that $g^{-1}U$ is open in $X\times\{y\}$

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think that really clicked with me. Thank you!

Comment: $g$ is *not* the identity function. $g$ is $I_{X\times Y}|_{X\times \{y\} }$. That's what @DustanLevenstein is referring to.

Comment: @MPW yes I understand, I've just proved the statement that he mentioned.

Comment: If $X$ is any space, $A$ a subspace of $X$, and $i:A\to X$ the inclusion, then $i$ is continuous by definition of the subspace topology. This has nothing to do with products.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $X\times Y$ is endowed with the producttopology and $p_{1}:X\times Y\rightarrow X$
and $p_{2}:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ are the projections then a function
$g:Z\rightarrow X\times Y$ is continuous if and only if the functions
$p_{1}\circ g:Z\rightarrow X$ and $p_{2}\circ g:Z\rightarrow Y$
are continous.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You need to take $U$ an open set in $X\times Y$ and prove that $g^{-1}U$ is open in $X\times\{y\}$.

Basically you need to prove that, $g^{-1}U=U\cap(X\times\{y\})$ where $U$ is an open set in $X\times Y$. All this needed because $X\times\{y\}$ has *subspace topology* of $X\times Y$.

Comment: i don't like this redaction, 'cuz it could be several ways to make $g^{-1}U$ relatively open to $X\times\{y\}$... anyway I will rewrite some time

Comment: only is missing $g^{-1}U=U\cap(X\times\{y\})$ and for that you need to complete: $$g^{-1}U\subset (U\cap(X\times\{y\})),$$ and $$g^{-1}U\supset (U\cap(X\times\{y\})).$$